# How to Create Register API with Feathersjs and Sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, feathersjs

I'm using the chat demo app from the Feathers docs to learn.
The question is, how I can input all the data into postgres database using a custom service.

Does anyone have a sample code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although this is entirely possible in a custom service, you can also use the already existing [feathers-sequelize](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-sequelize) and [feathers-knex](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-knex) adapters both which have support for PostgreSQL. To use them and decide which one to pick, you can read up more about [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) and [KnexJS](https://knexjs.org/).

In the [generating a service](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/chat/service.html) section you can then pick the adapter you want to use instead of `NeDB` and the CLI will guide you through the next steps and adjust the fields in the generated model files according to you needs.